# How to batch replace duplicates in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, duplicates

How to batch replace duplicated text strings from existing data?
I have an Excel file containing order#, PersonName, and ID, some of the (different) order# share a same set of PersonName and ID, which must be replaced with other unique PersonName and ID (it is ok for a same order# to have same PersonName and ID, but different order# must have different PersonName and ID). I have another existing data table containing a list of PersonName and ID for this replacing purpose, but how to write a formula to automatically replace all the duplicated PersonName and ID on different order# using this existing data table? The duplicates should not be deleted but only be replaced with unique string values.

Sample data (all data is unreal):

[image: Original Data]

Sample Vacant names and ID:

[image: Vacant names & ID]

And the result would replace the duplicate with the first available vacant names and ID (the same order# is assigned the same set of name and ID):

[image: sample output]

I'm really a novice on this, have spent quite much time searching for possibly similar questions and trying to figure out a solution but couldn't come up with one. :(

Comment: The question is not so clear, especially without sample data and explanatory result. It's also unclear what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: What does "all data is unreal" mean? Can you make the question a little more concise pls?

Comment: @sundqvist. When posting sample data, post it _as text_, so we don't have to retype it to test a solution.

Comment: Since, you have tagged VBA .. I don't think VBA is required for this. Just filter the data on "David Erent" then copy the Order# to a new sheet. Remove duplicates from there and then copy those unique Order# to Vacant Names & ID sheet as first column. Then You can simply fetch Person name and Id from the vacant names and Id sheet to your data sheet using VLOOKUP from the second David Erent row in your data. Don't sort any sheet during this. Thus you will get Maria Baker against 551872 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following vba code.
Column A = Order#, Column B = PersonName, Column D = ID, Vacant name = Column E, Column F = Vacant ID.

```
Sub SortData()
Dim Arr01 As Variant
Dim Arr02 As Variant

Dim i01 As Integer 'Temp int number
Dim i02 As Integer 'Temp int number
Dim i03 As Integer 'Temp int number
Dim i04 As Integer 'Temp int number


'Array of the "Order#, PersonName, ID"
Arr01 = Range("A2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))

'Array of the "Vacant name, Vacant ID"
Arr02 = Range("E2", Range("F2").End(xlDown))

i03 = 1
For i01 = 2 To UBound(Arr01, 1)
    For i02 = 1 To UBound(Arr01, 1)
        If i02 = i01 Then
            i02 = 1
            GoTo line1
        End If
        If Arr01(i02, 2) = Arr01(i01, 2) And Arr01(i02, 1) <> Arr01(i01, 1) Then
            Arr01(i01, 2) = Arr02(i03, 1)
            Arr01(i01, 3) = Arr02(i03, 2)
            i03 = 1 + i03
        End If
        
For i04 = i01 + 1 To UBound(Arr01, 1)
        If Arr01(i01, 1) = Arr01(i04, 1) Then
            Arr01(i04, 2) = Arr02(i01, 1)
            Arr01(i04, 3) = Arr02(i01, 2)
        End If
Next i04

        If i02 = i01 Then
            i02 = 1
            GoTo line1
        End If
    Next i02
line1:
Next i01

For i01 = i02 To UBound(Arr01, 1)
    For i02 = 1 To UBound(Arr01, 1)
        If Arr01(i01, 1) = Arr01(i02, 1) And Arr01(i01, 2) = Arr01(i02, 2) Then
            Arr01(i01, 3) = Arr01(i02, 3)
        End If
    Next i02
Next i01


Range("A2", Range("C2").End(xlDown)) = Arr01
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch Replace Duplicates (Double Dictionary)

- It is assumed that both tables (a contiguous range with one row of headers) start in cell `A1` on different worksheets.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub BatchReplaceDupes()
    
    ' Source (read from)
    Const sName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const snCol As Long = 1 ' Name Column
    Const siCol As Long = 2 ' ID Column
    
    ' Destination, Result (written to (also read from))
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const doCol As Long = 1 ' Order Column
    Const dnCol As Long = 2 ' Name Column
    Const diCol As Long = 3 ' ID Column
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the values from the Source Range to the Source Array.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Write the values from the Destination Range to the Destination Array.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim dData As Variant: dData = drg.Value
    
    ' Create references to the Order and Name Dictionaries.
    Dim dictO As Object: Set dictO = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim dictN As Object: Set dictN = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Declare variables.
    Dim KeyO As Variant ' Order
    Dim KeyN As Variant ' Name
    Dim KeyI As Variant ' ID
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim dc As Long
    Dim sr As Long: sr = 1 ' 1 is headers
    
    ' (Over)Write results to the Destination Array.
    For dr = 2 To UBound(dData, 1) ' 2, because 1 is headers
        KeyO = dData(dr, doCol)
        KeyN = dData(dr, dnCol)
        KeyI = dData(dr, diCol)
        If Not dictO.Exists(KeyO) Then
            If dictN.Exists(KeyN) Then
                sr = sr + 1
                dictO(KeyO) = sData(sr, snCol)
                dictN(KeyN) = sData(sr, siCol)
            Else
                dictO(KeyO) = KeyN
                dictN(KeyN) = KeyI
            End If
        End If
        dData(dr, dnCol) = dictO(KeyO)
        dData(dr, diCol) = dictN(KeyN)
    Next dr
    
    ' Write values from the Destination Array to the Destination Range.
    drg.Value = dData
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code (and also further down on line labelled `Source2`)
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table names in the `Source` and `Source2` lines of the pasted code to your "real" table names
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

**basic algorithm**

- Read in sampleData table
- *Read in the vacantName table for later use*
- Group by ID
- For each subtable in previous step, Group by Order#

  - Then add a 0-based index column to each sub-subtable
- Create a "lookup index" list that increments by one for each non-zero entry in the sampledata table. *We will use this to determine which vacant name to substitute*
- Create ID and PersonName columns using the second table if the index is <> 0

**M Code**

```
let

//change Table name in next line to actual name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="sampleData"]}[Content],

//Read in the vacant name list
//Again, change Table name in next line to actual name in your workbook
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="vacantNames"]}[Content],

//Group by ID
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID"}, {
        {"All", each _, type table [#"Order#"=number, PersonName=text, ID=text]}
        }),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"ID"}),

//Group each ID by Order#
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", each Table.Group([All],"Order#",{"All2", each _})),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"All"}),

//add index column to each subTable
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Custom.1", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Custom],"IDX",0,1,Int64.Type)),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom"}),

//expand tables
//we will replace names that do not have IDX=0
    #"Expanded Custom.1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns2", "Custom.1", 
        {"Order#", "All2", "IDX"}, {"Order#", "All2", "IDX"}),
    
//create index into vacant table
    vacIDX = List.Generate(()=>[vIDX=0, i=0],
                each [i] < Table.RowCount(#"Expanded Custom.1"),
                each [vIDX = if Table.Column(#"Expanded Custom.1","IDX"){[i]}=0 then [vIDX] else [vIDX]+1, i = [i]+1],
                each [vIDX]),
    
//Add index column to sample table
    #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded Custom.1", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//add Personal Names and ID
//The Index column gives us the position in the vacIDX list that corresponds to the "next" entry for substitution
//  into the sample table
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index1", "PersonName", 
        each if [IDX] = 0 then [All2][PersonName]{0} 
                else Source2[PersonName]{vacIDX{[Index]}}, Text.Type),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "ID", 
        each if [IDX] = 0 then [All2][ID]{0} 
                else Source2[ID]{vacIDX{[Index]}}, Text.Type),

//Remove unneeded columns and expand the table
    #"Removed Columns3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"Order#", "IDX", "Index"}),
    #"Expanded All2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns3", "All2", {"Order#"}, {"Order#"})
in
    #"Expanded All2"
```

**Results**
[image]